# OpsHub VS Migration tool running on port 9090. How to change port?

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I installed the OpsHub VS Online Migration tool on our TFS Server, which is also running JetBrains TeamCity. The TeamCity Build Agent is using port 9090.

When installing the OpsHub tool, it notified me that it also needs that port [9090]. Is it possible to reconfigure the tool to use a different port?

I would like to keep the current environment running as-is.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, you can try to install in another machine where 8989 and 9090 port is available or shutdown JetBrains TeamCity till migration is completed.